# Why do we need an invisible input when we make a custom checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox

I am going to customize an checkbox.

Generally, we create it by adding an invisible input and control value with it. Here is my mock code.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function Checkbox() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

  return (
    <label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={() => {
          setIsChecked(!isChecked);
        }}
      />
      <svg
        className={`checkbox ${isChecked ? "checkbox--active" : ""}`}
        aria-hidden="true"
        viewBox="0 0 15 11"
        fill="none"
      >
        ...
      </svg>
      Check me!
    </label>
  );
}
```

But I think we can do it without the invisible input.
Here is my mock code.

```
function Checkbox() {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div
      className={`checkbox ${isChecked ? 'checkbox--active' : ''}`}
      onClick={() => { setIsChecked(!isChecked) }}
    >
      <svg .../>
      Check me!
    </div>
  )
}
```

Are there will be side effect when we use div instead of input. If we use an invisible input, we should align 100% with the custom icon.

Answer (score 2):

It is mostly about the semantic such as for accessibility purpose (eg. screen readers). HTML provides a structured way to allow browser to understand exactly what you are trying to do (in this case, you are displaying a checkbox).

In addition, when used inside a `<form>` element, you are able to submit those checkbox states / values without resorting to maintaining the states in React. You can try it out by wrapping your `<input>` inside `<form>` and trigger the submit event.

Comment: I don't need to use form elements. It will be used without form elements and I think we can use "aria-role" for div.

Comment: The first rule of ARIA is if a native HTML element or attribute has the semantics and behavior you require, use it instead of re-purposing an element and adding ARIA. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/checkbox_role

Comment: Besides, input elements are **focusable** and accessible via **keyboard controls** (e.g skip to next via TAB key). Rebuilding this behavior for `<div>`  elements is rather unnecessarily complicated compared to hiding the native input elements.